# Syscall param socketcall.recvfrom(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c++, sockets, valgrind

When running this method, I get an error from Valgrind when calling `socket.getBytes`

```
void Client::register(VMap::VType type, char *id)
{
    const int sizeOfType = sizeof(type);
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeOfType);
    memcpy(buffer, &type, sizeOfType);
    socket.send(buffer, sizeOfType);
    sleep(1);
    char *bufferRecv = (char *) malloc(sizeOfType);
    memset(bufferRecv, 0 ,sizeOfType);
    int size = socket.getBytes(bufferRecv);

    free(buffer);
    free(bufferRecv);
}


int Socket::getBytes(char *buf)
{
    int ret = ::recv(m_sock, buf, MAXRECV, 0);

    return ret;
}
```

The error is:

```
==30653== Syscall param socketcall.recvfrom(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==30653==    at 0x58C214C: recv (recv.c:34)
==30653==    by 0x4E47B84: pippo::Socket::getBytes(char*) (Socket.cpp:115)
==30653==    by 0x4E48BAE: pippo::Rossi::register(pippo::sMap::Type, char*) (Rossi.cpp:80)
==30653==    by 0x4E48EEE: pippo::Rossi::initsMap(std::string) (Rossi.cpp:111)
==30653==    by 0x4E486B0: pippo::Rossi::Rossi(std::string, std::string, std::string, unsigned int) (Rossi.cpp:54)
==30653==    by 0x4E45884: test::TestRossi::testConstructor() (TestRossi.cpp:70)
==30653==    by 0x4E456D8: test::TestRossi::testBody() (TestRossi.cpp:48)
==30653==    by 0x5288D03: test::TestUnit::test() (TestUnit.cpp:42)
==30653==    by 0x5288513: test::TestRunner::run() (TestRunner.cpp:44)
==30653==    by 0x407F26: main (TestDUMBO.cpp:125)
==30653==  Address 0x67a9d64 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==30653==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30653==    by 0x4E48B21: pippo::Rossi::register(pippo::sMap::Type, char*) (Rossi.cpp:76)
==30653==    by 0x4E48EEE: pippo::Rossi::initsMap(std::string) (Rossi.cpp:111)
==30653==    by 0x4E486B0: pippo::Rossi::Rossi(std::string, std::string, std::string, unsigned int) (Rossi.cpp:54)
==30653==    by 0x4E45884: test::TestRossi::testConstructor() (TestRossi.cpp:70)
==30653==    by 0x4E456D8: test::TestRossi::testBody() (TestRossi.cpp:48)
==30653==    by 0x5288D03: test::TestUnit::test() (TestUnit.cpp:42)
==30653==    by 0x5288513: test::TestRunner::run() (TestRunner.cpp:44)
==30653==    by 0x407F26: main (TestDUMBO.cpp:125)
```

I really don't understand what's wrong. If, for example, I simply write inside the `bufferRecv` using a `sprintf`, I don't get any error.

The prototype of ::recv is the following:

```
/* Read N bytes into BUF from socket FD.
   Returns the number read or -1 for errors.

   This function is a cancellation point and therefore not marked with
   __THROW.  */
extern ssize_t recv (int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __n, int __flags);
```

**EDIT** Another info: If I declare the buffer like this `char bufferRecv[4];` I don't get any error from Valgrind.

Comment: What is `MAXRECV`? Anyways you should pass to `recvfrom()` the real size allocated to the buffer passed!

Comment: @alk I set MAXRECV to 500 while the data sent is only 4 bytes. Do you mean that in this case I should put 4? Yes it makes sense...

Comment: @alk FYI, putting the size as parameter fixed my issue! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others having the same issue:
As suggested by @alk I simply changed the getBytes method as follows:

```
int Socket::getBytes(char *buf, int sizeOfBuf)
{
    int ret = ::recv(m_sock, buf, sizeOfBuf, 0);


    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You might like to  accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, right, but I cannot accept it before two days. If you like to copy it in another answer I will accept yours and delete this